# Is it good or bad to use database query in controller yii2?

Tags: yii2

I am creating a project in which I am using database query in Controller. See the example.

```
public function actionView($id)
        {
            $imodel = $this->findModel($id);
            return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findModel($id),
                'UserInfo' => $this->UserNameById($imodel->Uid),

            ]);
        }

       public function UserNameById($id) { 
        $query = (new \yii\db\Query())->select(['UserName'])->from('user')->where(['Id' => [$id]]);
            $command = $query->createCommand();
            $data = $command->queryAll();
            return $data;
       }
```

Just I want to know that is it good or writing query in model file will be better.

like

```
public function actionView($id)
{
        $imodel = $this->findModel($id);
        $model = new User()
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'UserInfo' => $model >UserNameById($imodel->Uid),

        ]);
  }
```

..and now we can write the function in User Model.
So I want to know which one is better?
Writing **Database** query in **Model** Or **Controller**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MVC stands for Model,View Controller.

Generally most of in model always write DB operation like query.

To know more about YII mvc you can see here.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.mvc

I think it will be better if you write DB query in Model.